# how to fetch data from dynamically rendered component in angular

Tags: angular, components, angular-dynamic-components, angular13

I have rendered some child components (which has some forms and field) in a parent component, now I am unable to fetch data from those child component's form's fields

Comment: Checkout the `ControlValueAccessor` interface if your child components are part of a form. Also when asking questions provide code of what you have tried thus far, else people will not be able to realy help you.

Comment: well I haven't done anything as I can't figure it out how can I do it

Comment: Since you don't seem to be passing down any data to your child component, you could use `EventEmitter`s to receive data in the parent component, see https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter

Comment: there are multiple components (One component that is rendered multiple time on same screen )that are rendered and I will be fetching data from them all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to share data between components. One which could be via @Input / @Output. Some examples:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/sharing-data-between-angular-components-parent-to-1paiap?file=src%2Fapp%2Fparent%2Fparent.component.html

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-component-sharing-data-child-to-parent-rpgvld?file=src%2Fapp%2Fparent.ts

Or perhaps more suitable for your case could also be via service.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-angular-parent-and-children-communicat-fkrzvc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmission.service.ts